# javascript "static imports"

Tags: javascript, namespaces

Is there anything in javascript that is the equivalent of java static imports? For example, if I have a `Math` class that looks like

```
com.example.Math = function() {

   function1(...) {}
   function2(...) {}

}
```

Now some of these functions are naturally chained together such that the output to one is the input to another. I can do something like

```
com.example.Math.function2(com.example.Math.function1());
```

This is a little ugly looking, and I would really like to do something like:

```
function2(function1())
```

But I don't want to put function1 and function2 in the global namespace. Is this possible?

Comment: Are those functions static methods of `Math`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's called [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

```
with (com.example.Math) {
    function2(function1());
}
```

That said:

> Using `with` is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode). The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

For example:

```
var m = com.example.Math;
m.function2(m.function1());
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but according to MDN: `Using "with" is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode.`

Comment: Yea, `with` throws in the strict language. I wouldn't even mention it anymore.

Comment: @WesleyMurch `with` (as well as `eval`) is good when it is deliberately used.

Comment: Just thought I'd add that as the original answer was simply *"Yes, there is. It's called with."* My first thought was just use a variable, perhaps it would be a better solution after all.

Comment: See my comment to Sime as to why I would actually prefer with in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var Math = com.example.Math;
```

and then:

```
Math.fn1( Math.fn2(...) );
```

I'm assuming of course that your code is *not* global code. (If you're not familiar with the concept of avoiding global code in JS, read about the module pattern.)

---

You can go one step further:

```
var Math = com.example.Math,
    func1 = Math.func1,
    func2 = Math.func2;
```

and then:

```
func1( func2(...) );
```

Comment: While this will, work, my end goal is to create a fluent interface where the code reads like a person would write it outside of code. So having something like sin(cos(x)) is a lot more desireable than Math.sin(Math.cos(x)) especially as some the operations become more complex looking

Comment: @JeffStorey I've updated my answer. The general approach is to create local variables in your local environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
var O = function() {
  var that = {};
  var PI = Math.PI;
  that.circ = function(r) {
    return 2*PI*r;  
  };
  return that;
};
var o = O();
console.log(o.circ(1));
```

Notice how `PI` is used without the `Math` namespace in the `O.prototype.circ` method.

In JavaScript, there is no distinction between a namespace and an object, so some would argue that `Math` is not a namespace, but since JavaScript doesn't support the concept, it is as much a namespace as `com.mycompany.somelibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a closure to wrap the object.  It doesn't necessarily eliminate the object itself, but it helps with readability and if you are using a JS compressor can help reduce the output file size:

```
(function(Math) {
    Math.function2(Math.function1(...));
}(com.example.Math);)
```

You can also pass in multiple objects (ie: `function(Math, Foo) {...}(com.example.Math, com.example.Foo)`).

---

If you want to use just a few functions directly, just pass them in like this:

```
(function(function1, function2) {
    function2(function1(...));
}(com.example.Math.function1, com.example.Math.function2);)
```

This, however, removes the relationship between the Math instance and the functions, so you might get some weird behavior if your methods depend on instance variables.  As an example of how that won't work, imagine this class:

```
com.example.Counter = {
    counter: 0,
    increment: function() { this.counter++; }
}
```