# Static import in Javascript without 'with'

Tags: javascript, with-statement

**Context:** I have written a mini JS library for myself which is simply a collection of commonly used classes. I have followed the IIFE (http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) technique to separate my code into modules/classes and they're all grouped under a common global namespace var. Let's call it, `ns`. So we have a typical setup, `ns.ClassA`, `ns.ClassB`, etc. Now on the other hand, a separate script (main.js) is loaded at runtime and appended to the document, and this main.js contains the actual code that uses these classes.

**Goal:** I am trying to find an elegant way of accessing the classes inside main.js directly by calling the class name instead of having to access them through ns. . For example, I would want to be able to do `var a = new ClassA()`; instead of `var a = new ns.ClassA()`;

**Solutions researched & considered:**

1) the dreaded 'with' keyword ([javascript "static imports"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328245/javascript-static-imports)). In this case, I would do something like  `with(ns){ var a = new ClassA()}` , except I will have to wrap the entire main.js inside the `with(ns)` statement. This is undesirable for obvious reasons.

2) using locally declared variables.

`var ClassA = ns.ClassA, ClassB = ns.ClassB;`
and then, I will be able to instantiate ClassA and ClassB directly. However, this approach would require me to manually maintain the declaration, and it will just get very messy and hard to maintain as the number of classes increase in the  package.

3) pollute the global scope by injection

use a `for` loop to iterate over `ns` and map all the classes inside `ns`to global scope. This is clearly undesirable, and also it will create conflicts for cases such as ns.Event, ns.Audio etc.

4) PaperScript-style (http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/)

Inspired by PaperScript from PaperJS, where `PaperScript code is automatically executed in its own scope that without polluting with the global scope still has access to all the global browser objects and functions, such as document or window.` Looking at their source code on GitHub (sorry SO won't let me post any more links), they seem to be using some custom script pre-processing and then Acorn.js to parse. The end result is that one can directly refer to any class inside the `paper` object. For example, `var path = new Path()`  instead of `var path = new paper.Path()`, which is exactly what I wanted to achieve. However, my fear is that it might seem to be too much work to implement such a simple feature. So I wanted to see if any one has any ideas?

Thank you for taking your time to read this verbose description of the problem. Any inputs are appreciated.

Note: I have done my best in the past two days into researching this topic, please forgive me if I missed any obvious solutions. In addition, if there's no easy solution to this, I will simply stick with the `ns.ClassA` pattern. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Pick the one you're most comfortable with, or throw it all out and just use [Require](http://requirejs.org/). This is gonna get closed as "primarily opinion-based."

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was wondering if there's other alternative solutions besides the ones I have listed?

Comment: Every problem has many solutions; questions of the nature `which solution is best` are not valuable.

Comment: I apologize for not making myself clear. Indeed, questions of the nature 'which solution is best' is primarily opinion-based, and that's not the question intended to be asked here. I have evaluated and assessed each solution for myself, as you can see from the question itself. I simply want to know if there are other possible solutions I have overlooked. Thank you for your input and concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but I believe you could create a prototype of String and set your vars like so

```
String.prototype.ns = function(){
    return new ns[this]();
}
var ca = "ClassA".ns();
```